# 5 = 11 mod x --> Is the Answer x = 6 or x = 2,3,6? I find different answers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We've started with Modulo in school and I'm currently trying to solve this:

Find x: 5 = 11 mod x

In my opinion there's only one solution: x = 6

But my teacher gave us his solutions: x = {2, 3, 6} (and 0,1)

I don't understand why 2 or 3 is an answer because: 
11 mod 2 = 1 and 11 mod 3 = 2 --> NOT 5!

Am I doing something wrong? Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Note that $5\equiv 3\equiv 11\equiv\dots\mod 2$.  Similarly for $3$, we have $2\equiv 5\equiv 8\equiv 11\equiv\dots\mod 3$.  The trivial cases ($0,1$) should be fairly clear as well.

Comment: 11 mod 2 = 1 (because $11=2 \times 5 +1$) and also 5 mod 2 =1 (because $5 = 2 \times 2 +1$).

Comment: And 11 mod 3 = 2 (because $11=3×3+2$) and also 5 mod 3 =2 (because $5=3×1+2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 = 11 mod x is shorthand for 5 mod x = 11 mod x (this "feature" of the mod x notation can be confusing).

Therefore (11 - 5) mod x = 0.

Or, in other words, 6 mod x = 0. So x is a factor of 6.

This is how your teachers reaches the answer x = 1, 2, 3 or 6 (I disagree with x=0 because I don't think "mod 0" makes any sense).

Checing the case x = 2 we have 5 mod 2 = 1 and 11 mod 2 = 1 so 5 mod 2 = 11 mod 2.

Comment: MathJAX?$\qquad$

Comment: Alright I see... I didn't know about that notation before. Thanks for your help, much appreciated! This notation is just a bit weird because if you're trying to find only 5 = 11 mod x (not 5 mod x = 11 mod x) you'd still have to write it like that and get all the answers :D

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of "equivalence modulo $x$", we have $5 \equiv 11 \pmod{x}$ if and only if $x$ divides $(11 - 5) = 6$. This is where the set $x \in \{1,2,3,6\}$ comes from.

In this case, "$\bmod$" is not being used as a function that reduces numbers modulo $x$. While you can define a function like that (or perform minor contortions to get the solution set using that function), the question is really about "congruence modulo $x$" as a relation on the set of integers.